# How to open an openssl s_client socket in Python

Tags: sockets, openssl

i am new to Python, i need to open a socket using Openssl in Python for the below command, which is working directly.

openssl s_client -CAfile trust.cer -cert server.cer -key server_key.pem -port 31114 -host 10.238.110.110 -tls1 -quiet –crlf

this is required for firing some MML Commands using the CLI on the server 10.238.110.110 in our private network

```
import socket
import ssl
import sys
import os
class Client:
    def __init__(self,host,port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = None
        self.connected = False

    def connect(self):
        data = []
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        self.sock.settimeout(15)
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.host,self.port))

            #self.connected = True
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if ( not data):
                self.connected = False
                print("not connected")
            else:
                self.connected = True
                print("connected")
        except IOError as e:
            self.connected = False
            print("error")
```

Its always printing not connected. on Wireshark also it shows the server is finishing the connection.
Please help me with the code

Answer (score 1):

```
def connect(self):
    data = []
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setblocking(0)
    self.sock.settimeout(15)
    # WRAP SOCKET
    wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

    try:
        wrappedSocket.connect((self.host,self.port))

    #self.connected = True
    data = self.sock.recv(1024)
    if ( not data):
        self.connected = False
        print("not connected")
    else:
        self.connected = True
        print("connected")
    except IOError as e:
        self.connected = False
    print("error")
```

try this

Comment: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:833)

Comment: I am seeing the attempt on wireshark but it is terminated from server side and I am getting above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to socket using the below code. Thanks for the support everyone.

```
import socket
import ssl
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
addr=("10.200.200.101",31114)
wrapper = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
wrapper.connect(addr)
```